# MS Excel 2013 - Function based upon different cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to use an error checking argument.  I want to use the values of two cells (in this case H19 and Q19) to determine a pass or fail argument.  The issue is that it is possible for two values to end up with a pass conclusion for cell Q19 ("A40" or "A41") when compared to H19.

Here is a working function with only a value of "A40" in cell "Q19":

```
`=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A19,2))),IF(AND(LEFT(B19,1)="A",H19<>"oor",Q19<>"A40"),"Fail",IF(AND(LEFT(B19,1)<>"a",H19<>"OOR",Q19<>"A40"),"Fail",IF(H19="OOR",IF(LEFT(Q19,1)="A","Fail","Pass"),IF(LEFT(Q19,1)<>"A","Fail","Pass")))),"")`
```

I want to expand this to include the new parameters of either "A40" or "A41" being in cell "Q19", similar to this:

```
`=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A19,2))),IF(AND(LEFT(B19,1)="A",H19<>"oor",Q19<>"A40"),"Fail",IF(AND(LEFT(B19,1)<>"a",H19<>"OOR",Q19<>"A40"),"Fail",IF(AND(LEFT(B19,1)="A",H19<>"oor",Q19<>"A41"),"Fail",IF(AND(LEFT(B19,1)<>"a",H19<>"OOR",Q19<>"A41"),"Fail",IF(H19="OOR",IF(LEFT(Q19,1)="A","Fail","Pass"),IF(LEFT(Q19,1)<>"A","Fail","Pass")))))),"")`
```

Here is a screenshot from the spreadsheet to hopefully clarify it a little:

[image: Spreadsheet Example]

Comment: Your formulas are quite complicated, it's difficult to understand them, please post some sample data and share current and expected output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Please refer to revision below)*

<s>Is this what you are trying to achieve?</s>

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A19,2))),IF(AND(UPPER(LEFT(B19,1))="A",UPPER(H19)="OOR",OR(UPPER(Q19)="A40",UPPER(Q19)="A41")),"Pass","Fail"),"")
```

---

## EDIT

Following the discussion in the comments, the formula provided by @Bandersnatch should fulfil your requirements:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A19,2))),IF(AND(LEFT(B19,1)="A",H19<>"oor",OR(Q19="A40",Q19="A41")),"Pass","Fail"),"")
```

**Observe:**

(Click on the image to view at full resolution)

[image]

Note that for validation:

- The first two characters of `A19` must be numerical (e.g. `12ABC`)
- The first character of cell `B19` must be `A` (e.g. `A12`)
- `H19` must be anything other than `OOR` (case-insensitive)
- `Q19` must be either `A40` or `A41` (case-insensitive)

Comment: Actually no.  What I'm trying to do is get a "Pass" result if the contents of Q19 are either "A40" or "A41", if the contents of H19 are anything other than "OOR" or "oor".  Obviously the result would be "Fail" if it were anything else.  I pasted your code into the "BL19" cell of my spreadsheet and it automatically results in "Fail" with both the "A40" and "A41" data residing in Q19.

On a very positive note - I love the idea of shortening my function as much as you did!

:-)

Comment: So to get "Pass", Q19 has to be "A40" or "A41" AND H19 has to NOT be "OOR" or "oor"?  No other conditions?

Comment: And Excel considers "OOR" and "oor" to be the same thing unless you use "EXACT(). I think.

Comment: How 'bout this: `=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A19,2))),IF(AND(LEFT(B19,1)="A",H19<>"oor",OR(Q19="A40",Q19="A41")),"Pass","Fail"),"")`

Comment: That is basically correct.  H19 will typically be "NMCS", "NMNM", "PMCS", or "PMCM", but I don't think it matters for the purpose of this function.  I pasted in your function and it doesn't validate (always fails).  I don't see a way to PM on this forum, but if it can be done, I can send you the spreadsheet to work with, if you like.  Thank you for your help, tho!

Comment: @Drazzminius, what are the values of `A19`, `B19`, `H19`, and `Q19` for which the function provided by @Bandersnatch returns `"Fail"` and you believe it should return `"Pass"`?

Comment: If:
A19 = a number
B19 = a designation (aircraft type). I believe this is just to validate the use of the function.
H19 = Anything other than OOR
Q19 = either A40 or A41
Then the result should "PASS"

A fail result is when any of these cells do not meet this criteria.  Right now, I believe the hiccup is Q19's validation as either A40 or A41.  In the original post, I provided an example of a passing function for validation of a single of only A40; it is when trying to get either of these (A40 or A41) that I'm running into issues.

Comment: @Drazzminius Please refer to my revised answer above.

Comment: @LeeMac - That is it!  The validation was failing because of the argument requiring the "A" in B19 (I'm not sure why this working in the  original functions, but as you can guess, I didn't write them.  You have been a tremendous help and I sincerely appreciate it!

Comment: @Drazzminius, you're most welcome - I'm glad we got there in the end :-)